# Jacobian Eigenvalue Algorithm and Positive definiteness of Eigenvalue matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

For a **real symmetric matrix A of size n x n**, the **Jacobian Eigenvalue Algorithm** produces

- **n - Eigen values of A** in the form of a Square Diagonal Eigenvalue Matrix of order n
- **n - Eigen vectors of A** corresponding to each of the n-Eigen values of A in the form of a n x n Matrix with columns as Eigen vectors.

Also, a matrix is said to be **positive definite** if it’s symmetric and all its eigenvalues are non-negative i.e. every Eigenvalue > 0.

**Does the Jacobi Eigenvalue algorithm guarantees producing a positive definite Eigenvalue diagonal matrix for every real symmetric matrix A ?**

**If the answer to above queestion is no, then**

- What must be changed so that Jacobi algorithm guarantees producing a positive definite Eigenvalue diagonal matrix ?
- If Jacobi Algorithm cannot guarantee that, are there any alternative iterative methods that produce n-Eigenvalues and n-Eigen vectors but guarantee producing a positive definite Eigenvalue matrix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eigenvalue algorithm produces a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$.  That matrix is positive definite if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive.

So, generally we will not get a positive definite eigenvalue matrix.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1st part of your answer is same as I stated in the question. About the second part of your answer, is their a way to always get a positive definite eigenvalue matrix ?

Comment: Yes, take the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix

Comment: Ok, so only if A is positive definite itself that its Eigenvalue matrix will be positive definite. Makes some sense

Comment: @nurabha it's obvious when you realize that the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are just its diagonal entries.

Comment: I am new to Diagnolization based on iterative methods, so probably didn't get the obvious concepts initially. Now I get them. Thanks for help!